Gradient of $\ln \det(R(x)) + q(x)^H R(x)^{-1} q(x)$ w.r.t. $x$, where $R(x)=a X^H X + bI$, $q(x)=a X^H y$, and $X = x^T \otimes I$
I need to find the gradient of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$:

$f(x) = \ln \det(R(x)) + q(x)^H R(x)^{-1} q(x)$,

where

$R(x)=a X^H X + bI$,
$q(x)=a X^H y$,
$X = x^T \otimes I$
$\otimes$ denotes Kronecker product
$I$ represents an identity matrix
$(\cdot)^H$ means complex conjugate transpose, i.e., Hermitian operator


Please see my half-baked work as I don't know how to proceed. Assuming non-complex-valued set-up for simplicity, that is, replacing Hermitian with simply transpose, and rewriting the function $\overline{f}(x) = \ln \det(a X(x)^T X(x) + bI) + q(x)^T (a X(x)^T X(x) + bI)^{-1} q(x)$, $q(x) = a X^T y$. Then, I think for complex-valued, one can remove factor 2 and replace transpose operator with Hermitian.
From here, How to arrive at $ \frac{\partial }{\partial X} \log(\mathrm{det}(I + A X B^\top )) = A^\top (I +B X^\top A^\top )^{-1} B$?
I can find the gradient of at least $\ln \det(a X(x)^T X(x) + bI)$ with respect to $X(x)$
\begin{align}
\nabla_X \ln \det(a X(x)^T X(x) + bI) = 2aX(x)^T \left(a X(x)^T X(x) + bI\right)^{-1}.
\end{align}
For complex-valued, I think, we have
\begin{align}
\nabla_X^{*} \ln \det(a X(x)^H X(x) + bI) = a X(x)^H \left(a X(x)^H X(x) + bI\right)^{-1},
\end{align}
correct?
For the second component, I am not sure how to proceed.
Anyway, I am badly stuck with this problem and don't know how to proceed. Your help will be highly appreciated.

What have you tried?

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left(#1\right)}$
$\def\vec{\operatorname{vec}}$
$\def\re{\operatorname{Re}}$
$\def\im{\operatorname{Im}}$
$\def\xo{\overline{x}}$
$\def\nx{\lVert x \rVert}$
$\def\ny{\lVert y \rVert}$
$\def\C{\mathbb{C}}$
$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
There is lack of clarity in the definitions in this question. I am assuming
$x,y \in \C^n$ and
$a,b \in \R.$
Furthermore, since $X=x^T \otimes I$ and (I assume) $I$ is $I_n$, $X \in \C^{n \times n^2}$ which means $X^HX \in \C^{n^2 \times n^2}$. Therefore the $I$ in the definition $R=aX^HX+bI$ is $I_{n^2}=I_n \otimes I_n$. I will denote $I_n$ as $I$.
From the definitions $R=aX^HX+bI_{n^2}$ and $X=x^T\otimes I$
$$
R = a (x^T \otimes I)^H (x^T\otimes I) + bI_{n^2} \\
R = a (\xo \otimes I) (x^T\otimes I) + bI_{n^2} \\
R = a (\xo x^T) \otimes I + bI_{n^2} \\
R = (a\xo x^T+bI) \otimes I  
$$
($\xo$ is the complex conjugate of $x$) and, using the Sherman-Morrison formula,
$$
(a\overline{x}x^T+bI)^{-1}
=
b^{-1}I - \frac{a b^{-2}\overline{x}x^T}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}.
$$
($\nx^2=x^T \xo = x^H x$) the inverse of $R$ is
$$
R^{-1} = \qty{b^{-1}I - \frac{a b^{-2}\overline{x}x^T}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}}
\otimes I = M \otimes I.  
$$
From the definition
$$
q=aX^H y 
$$
we can write
$$
q^H R^{-1} q =a^2 y^H X R^{-1} X^H y.
$$
Since
$$
X=x^T \otimes I
$$
we have
$$
X R^{-1} X^H = (x^T \otimes I) (M \otimes I) (\xo \otimes I) = \qty{(x^T M)\otimes I}(\xo \otimes I)=(x^TM\xo) \otimes I.
$$
From the definition of $M$
$$
x^T\qty{b^{-1}I - \frac{a b^{-2}\overline{x}x^T}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}}\xo
=
b^{-1}x^T \xo - \frac{a b^{-2}x^T\overline{x}x^T\xo}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}
=
b^{-1}x^T \xo - \frac{a b^{-2}(x^T \xo)^2}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}
=\frac{x^T \xo}{ a x^T \xo+b}
$$
and so
$$
q^H R^{-1} q = \frac{x^T \xo}{ a x^T \xo+b} a^2 \ny^2=
\qty{1-\frac{b}{ a x^T \xo+b}}  a \ny^2.
$$
From this we obtain
$$
d(q^H R^{-1} q)
=\frac{b}{ (a \nx^2+b)^2} a^2 \ny^2 dx^T \xo.
$$
Since $d \log \det R = \tr R^{-1} dR$ and
$$
dR=a\xo dx^T \otimes I 
$$
we can write
$$
 R^{-1} dR =
(M \otimes I ) (a\xo dx^T \otimes I )
=
(a M\xo dx^T) \otimes I.
$$
As in the last evaluation
$$
aM\xo dx^T=ab^{-1}\xo dx^T-
\frac{a^2 b^{-2}\xo x^T\xo dx^T}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}
=ab^{-1}\xo dx^T-
\frac{a^2 b^{-2}\nx^2\xo dx^T}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}
=
\frac{ab^{-1}\xo dx^T}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2}
$$
and so
$$
\tr R^{-1} dR =\frac{ab^{-1}}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2} \tr ( \xo dx^T \otimes I)
=
\frac{ab^{-1}}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2} \tr(\xo dx^T ) \tr I
=n \frac{ab^{-1}}{1 + a b^{-1}\nx^2} dx^T \xo.
$$
Collecting all terms we have
$$
df =
n \frac{a}{a \nx^2+ b} dx^T \xo+
\frac{b}{ (a \nx^2+b)^2} a^2 \ny^2 dx^T \xo
=
\frac{a(n\nx^2+b\ny^2)+nb}{ (a \nx^2+b)^2}
ax^H dx
$$
and so
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^T}=
\frac{a(n\nx^2+b\ny^2)+nb}{ (a \nx^2+b)^2}
ax^H.
$$

$+\tt1;$ Nice answer ....and quite a display of algebraic persistence to get there.

It is not a good idea to post an answer after @greg. I hope there are no mistakes...

Thank you so much!!
